# Printing a list with string.format rounding for float members

Tags: python

If I have a list of the format `['ABC',0.1234,'DEF']` and I wanted to print it out doing something like

```
l = ['ABC',0.1234,'DEF']
print('\t'.join(map(str, l)))
```

But I would also like to round the float so that the output would be `ABC\t0.12\tDEF`.

I can do it with something like:

```
a,b,c = l
print('{}\t{:.2f}\t{}'.format(a,b,c))
```

But since l is just one member of a much larger list, I would like to be able to do this with a list comprehension or something more pythonic.

Comment: You mean something like this? `print('{}\t{:.2f}\t{}'.format(*l))`

Comment: Yes sPaz exactly. If you answer with it i'll accept it. I always forget about using *. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can simply do this for a big list:

```
print('{}\t{:.2f}\t{}'.format(*l))
```

Note that `.format()` also supports indexing the list. Something like:

```
print('0[0] 0[1] 0[2]'.format(l))
```

**Edit:**

"The data structure here is a list of triplet lists. Is there any straightforward way to do string formatting on a unknown size list?"
You can try:

```
>>> print('\t'.join("{:.2f}".format(x) if isinstance(x, float) else str(x) for k
 in l for x in k))
```

Comment: but that will only do it for the first 3 items in said big list right?

Comment: The data structure here is a list of triplet lists. Is there any straightforward way to do string formatting on a unknown size list?

Comment: @IanFiddes From jonrsharpe's answer, you can further add a nested for loop to handle that case. I have edited my answer to refect the change.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
print('\t'.join("{:.2f}".format(x) if isinstance(x, float) else str(x) for x in l))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define a function for this:

```
def float_or_str(x):
    try:
        return '{:.2f}'.format(x)
    except ValueError:
        return '{}'.format(x)

l = ['ABC',0.1234,'DEF']
print('\t'.join(map(float_or_str, l)))
```

yields

```
ABC 0.12    DEF
```